# ¿Cómo puedo truncar la parte horaria de un datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una columna `DATETIME` con horas, minutos y segundos, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT GETDATE()

2020-07-22 20:57:15.983
```

Y a los efectos de las consultas que necesito realizar, me resultaría mucho más cómodo que este dato solo tenga información de la fecha. ¿Como convertir entonces un `DATETIME` a una fecha sin hora pero manteniendo el tipo de dato?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasta versión 2008 de **Sql Server**, solo disponíamos del tipo `DATETIME` por lo que "truncar" la parte horaria de una columna había que hacerla, por ejemplo así:

```
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Este un método un poco extraño de leer pero sumamente efectivo y rápido. Obtenemos la diferencia en días desde el día 0 y el actual y sumamos esa cantidad al día 0, que en el caso de SQL Server es el 01-01-1900, esto "elimina" la parte horaria de cualquier fecha.

Otro de los métodos clásicos es pasar por un `VARCHAR` formateado sin la hora y luego volverlo a convertir en un `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) , 120)
```

A partir de la versión antes mencionada, disponemos del tipo de dato `DATE` por lo que también podemos hacer esto:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Para más información:

- [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)
- [Most efficient way in SQL Server to get date from date+time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133081/most-efficient-way-in-sql-server-to-get-date-from-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

Una manera más estándar de lograrlo es utilizar la función `cast()` para convertir a `Date`  y luego de vuelta a `DateTime`:

```
select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```

Desde mi punto de vista es preferible escribirlo de esta forma porque la función `cast()` está soportada en un gran número de motores, y la tendencia es a que cada vez la soporten más.

Otra forma de lograr el resultado podría ser convertir el valor a un número de coma flotante, valiéndose del hecho que internamente la fecha se almacena de esta forma, quitarle los decimales, por ejemplo utilizando la función `floor()` y convertirlo de nuevo a `DateTime`:

```
select cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

Esto funcionará en [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), [firebird](/questions/tagged/firebird) y otros motores que internamente almacenan la fecha como números de coma flotante.

Answer (score 0):

yo tenía el mismo problema y lo que hice fue que lo trunqué de esta manera y solo me muestra día y mes:

```
FORMAT (date, 'dd-MM')
```